# Reselect - how to pass a result of one selector to another as an argument before combiner function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reselect

I have a selector that looks like this:

```
export const shipmentsRejectedSelector: (
  state: AppStateType,
  departmentIds: List<number>,
  currentDate: DateTime,
  toDate: DateTime
) => List<Shipment> = createImmutableEqualSelector(
  shipmentsByDepartmentIdsAndDate,
  packageEvents,
  (shipments, events) =>
    shipments
      .valueSeq()
      .filter(s => s.get('state') == EventType.REJECTED))
      ?.toList() || List()
)
```

Since `packageEvents` returns all `events` no matter what shipments it is part of, I would like to return only events that are part of the shipments returned by the `shipmentsByDepartmentIdsAndDate` selector. How can I pass `shipmentIds` to a new selector that would fetch only events that have the `shipmentIds` that I am passing?
Something like this for example:

```
export const shipmentsRejectedSelector: (
      state: AppStateType,
      departmentIds: List<number>,
      currentDate: DateTime,
      toDate: DateTime
    ) => List<Shipment> = createImmutableEqualSelector(
      shipmentsByDepartmentIdsAndDate,
      shipments => packageEvents(shipments),
      (shipments, events) =>
        shipments
          .valueSeq()
          .filter(s => s.get('state') == EventType.REJECTED))
          ?.toList() || List()
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you've not shown how you are using the `event` object in resultFunc(combiner). So I am guessing you want to add events to the shipments before filtering them.

One way could be to use the `packageEvents` in combiner:

```
const shipmentsByDepartmentIdsAndDate = ...;
const shipmentWithPackageEvents = createSelector(shipments, (shipments)=>{//return shipments along with the corresponding events});

const shipmentsRejectedSelector = createSelector(
      shipmentsByDepartmentIdsAndDate,
      (shipments) =>
        shipmentWithPackageEvents(shipments).valueSeq()
          .filter(s => s.get('state') == EventType.REJECTED))
          ?.toList() || List()
    )
```

Or we can directly use shipmentWithPackageEvents:

```
const shipmentsByDepartmentIdsAndDate = ...;
const shipmentWithPackageEvents = createSelector(shipments, (shipments)=>{//return shipments along with the corresponding events});

const shipmentsRejectedSelector = createSelector(
      shipmentWithPackageEvents,
      (shipments) =>
        shipments.valueSeq()
          .filter(s => s.get('state') == EventType.REJECTED))
          ?.toList() || List()
    )
```